# Dynamic member pointer array

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, pointer-to-member

Is it possible to create a dynamic array to save the names of each variable in a structure?

```cpp
typedef struct dataSave {
    uint8_t nb;
    bool state;
    uint16_t dataIRArray[512];
} dataSave_t;

dataSave_t mysave;

template <typename T>
struct config_t {
    auto T::*var;
    char* name;
};

const config_t<dataSave_t> config[] = {
    {&dataSave_t::nb, "nb"},
    {&dataSave_t::state, "state"},
    {&dataSave_t::dataIRArray, "dataIRArray"}
};
```

The types of the structure's variables are different, and always generate an error:

> error: non-static data member declared with placeholder 'auto'

I need to create something similar to dynamically going through a JSON and converting the JSON data just by adding it to the config list.

Comment: Why do you need this in the first place? You can't have a pointer to data that isn't instantiated.

Comment: json data is just text, text with a conversion function. You could eg store functions with signature `void (const std::string&)` that internally convert to right type and store the value in a member

Comment: Please explain how are you going to use that array of `config_t` structures. I think you'll face more problems there.

Comment: Look into `std::variant` to hold values of different types. For instance, the `config_t::var` member can be declared as `std::variant<uint8_t T::*, bool T::*, uint16_t (T::*)[512]>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want something like this:

```
  template <typename owner>
  struct desc_base
  {
      virtual ~desc_base() = default;
      virtual std::string to_string(const owner&) = 0;
      virtual void from_string(owner&, std::string_view) = 0;
      const std::string name;
      desc_base(std::string_view name) : name(name) {}
  };
  
  template <typename owner, typename member>
  struct desc : desc_base<owner>
  {
      member owner::*ptr;
      std::string to_string(const owner& o) override { return my_to_string(o.*ptr); }
      void from_string(owner& o, std::string_view s) override { my_from_string(s, o.*ptr); }
      desc (member owner::*ptr, std::string_view name) : desc_base<owner>(name), ptr(ptr) {}
  };
  
  template <typename owner, typename member>
  std::unique_ptr<desc<owner, member>>
  make_desc(member owner::*ptr, std::string_view name) { return std::make_unique<desc<owner, member>>(ptr, name); }
  
  const std::unique_ptr<desc_base<dataSave_t>> config[] {
      make_desc(&dataSave_t::nb, "nb"),
      make_desc(&dataSave_t::state, "state"),
      make_desc(&dataSave_t::dataIRArray, "dataIRAArray")
  };
```

This uses basic polymorphism technique to store an array of (smart pointers to) base class objects, where all the real work being done by the derived objects via virtual functions. Real work in this case being `from_string` and `to_string`. You can replace them with functions doing whatever real work you need to do, or just define `my_to_string` and `my_from_string`.